# Inserir quebra de linha, numa resposta AJAX

Tags: php, html, html5, ajax

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema com fins didáticos, so que não consigo fazer uma simples quebra de linha.

O Sistema é basicamente um preenchimento de alguns inputs, onde ao clicar num botão ele faz a leitura desses campos e monta uma mensagem, que eu exibo na mesma pagina através de ajax.

HTML

```
<div class="alert alert-success text-center invisible"></div>
```

AJAX

```
let formulario = document.forms.formulario;
formulario.addEventListener('submit', function(event){

event.preventDefault();

var dados = {};
dados.nome = formulario.nome.value;
dados.tel = formulario.tel.value;
dados.pet = formulario.pet.value;
dados.medico = formulario.medico.value;

var dadosTexto = JSON.stringify(dados);

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'modalCadastroCliente');
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

xhr.onload = function(){
    var mensagem = document.querySelector("div.alert");
    mensagem.classList.remove("invisible");
    mensagem.textContent = xhr.responseText;
    
}

xhr.send(dadosTexto);
});
```

PHP

```
<?php
include_once('conexao.php');

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate'); 
header("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");

$json = file_get_contents("php://input");
$obj = json_decode($json);

/* {"nome":"Erick","tel":"37999750686","pet":"Bento","medico":"Lara"} */
$nome = $obj->{'nome'};
$tel = $obj->{'tel'};
$pet = $obj->{'pet'};
$medico = $obj->{'medico'};


$nomeCript =  base64_encode($nome);

$url = 'localhost/pesquisa-satisfacao?' . 'id=' . $nomeCript;

$msg = "<p>Olá " . $nome . ", somos do Hospital Veterinário Santa Clara.
Agradecemos a confiança de nos deixar cuidar e atender o(a) " . $pet . " 
Ficaremos muito feliz se puder nos ajudar respondendo algumas perguntas, 
prometo que não gastara mais de 1 minuto! So acessar o link a baixo:</p>" . " 
<p>" . $url . "</p>";

$sql = "INSERT INTO clientes (nome, pet, medico, tel, urls, created) VALUES
('$nome', '$pet', '$medico', '$tel', '$url', NOW())";
$sql = $pdo->query($sql);


if($nome AND $tel AND $pet AND $medico != '' ){
    echo $msg;
}else{
    echo "Algo de errado não esta certo...";
}
```

Eu queria separa a URL da msg, tipo forçar uma quebra de linha so que não esta dando dessa forma que eu fiz o navegador não interpreta as tag pois parece que tudo ficou dentro de uma string

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém tem alguma sugestão de como posso fazer para melhorar a formatação desta mensagem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver alterando esta parte

```
xhr.onload = function(){
    var mensagem = document.querySelector("div.alert");
    mensagem.classList.remove("invisible");
    mensagem.textContent = xhr.responseText;
    
}
```

O textContent funciona imprimindo uma string bruta ao alterar para innerHTML funcionou ficando assim

```
xhr.onload = function(){
    var mensagem = document.querySelector("div.alert");
    mensagem.classList.remove("invisible");
    mensagem.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia, acredito que o `\n` possa ajudar ou até mesmo um `<br>`, caso queira algo com maior controle, pode tentar usar o [split com javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Comment: eu já tentei utilizar tanto o \n quanto o <br> so que a quebra de linha não é acontece simplesmente ele imprime a tag, vou pesquisar sobre este split